# OpenCL Correct way to share Buffers between multiple devices of same platform

Tags: c++, memory-management, gpu, opencl, multi-gpu

I use One context and a command queue for each device.

After every clEnqueueWriteBuffer() i use

```
clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects(CommandQueue, 1, &Memory, CL_MIGRATE_MEM_OBJECT_CONTENT_UNDEFINED, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

If I want to Share Buffer Between Devices of the Same Platform would the above be the correct and fastest away?

Extra:

Is it faster to use clEnqueueWriteBuffer() after clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects()?

Also, does clSetKernelArg() have any overhead when calling it?

Comment: Been over 2 days... can anybody please tell me!